# Find item in array that has most word frequency

Tags: ruby, hash

I am trying to choose the value `2` without the `"Ten"` key.

```
most_count = %w(Five Ten Six Eleven Ten Six One)
word_frequency = Hash.new(0)
most_count.each {|word| word_frequency[word] += 1}
word_frequency.max_by { |k,v| v }
# => ["Ten", 2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
word_frequency.max_by { |k,v| v }.last
```

Or, one might sort:

```
word_frequency.sort_by { |k,v| -v }
```

and then find a max value:

```
word_frequency.sort_by { |k,v| -v }.max
#⇒ ["Ten", 2]
word_frequency.sort_by { |k,v| -v }.max.last
#⇒ 2
```

Please also note, that the result `["Ten", 2]` is not absolutely correct, since there could be many items with the same count. Most precise solution will group by value and operate on the result:

```
# ⇓⇓⇓ this will get all 2s  ⇓⇓⇓
word_frequency.group_by(&:last).to_a.last.first
#⇒ 2
```

Comment: Thanks for great explanation!   Interesting, I got it. :)

Comment: I wonder now if I find "Six" and "Ten" which are both most frequently words in keys.  `word_frequency.max.first`  => "Ten".  "Six" is missing?

Comment: `max` returns the only value. Just use `group_by` as mentioned in the last snippet: `word_frequency.group_by(&:last).to_a.last.last.map(&:first)`. Not quite elegant, but you might try to play with a result of `group_by` yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You could just do

```
word_frequency.max_by { |k,v| v }.last
```

Comment: `max` will implicitly convert the hash into an array, leading to array comparison. Then it will be primarily sorted by the original key of the hash. It is just a coincidence that `"Ten"` is alphabetically the last within the keys.

Comment: You are right. This only works as Ten is the last one in the alphabetical order. So my answer was wrong, I will update it. Thanks @sawa.